# Windows Command To List Expired Accounts And Exclude Accounts Set To Never

Tags: windows, powershell, command

Using a command, I would like to list expired user accounts on my machine and exclude accounts where that parameter displays an empty value or is set to Never.

The PowerShell command below lists all expired user account:

```
get-localuser | Where-Object { $_.AccountExpires -le (Get-Date)}
```

Example output:

```
Name           AccountExpires
----           --------------
Administrator    
Guest           
test           09/05/2021 00:00:00
```

I would like to exclude the users that display a blank entry as this indicates that the expiry value for that user is set to Never. Is there a way to change the PowerShell command to say AND NOT values equal to blank or set to Never?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the null test to `Where-Object`

```
Get-LocalUser | 
    Where-Object { $_.AccountExpires -le (Get-Date) -and $null -ne $_.AccountExpires } | 
    Select-Object Name, AccountExpires
```

`-ne` means Non Equal, so when AccountExpires is null, it will be not retrieved.

Comment: Thank you once again for the help, the command you shared works perfectly, however, sometimes, I get the odd Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index') error message. I think this relates to the $null paramter, is there a workaround for this expression/match?

Comment: This commande as is should not flush this error, have you add a treatment with something like `$result.Count` ? (sorry for late answer)